# Update Apache - already installed and latest version

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to update apache to 2.4.51 on my AMI server, but when I do `sudo yum update httpd -y` it's says:

`Package httpd-2.4.48-2.amzn2.x86_64 already installed and latest version`.

Do you know how can I update my server to the new version of Apache?
I've tried to install the new package by doing a gzip but it doesn't seems to work either.

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: What is the output of `httpd -v`?

Comment: If that package has only recently been added to the repo, you might need to clean your cache? `sudo yum clean all`

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, the sudo yum clean all, works great! Thanks a lot guys.